# How do I run a python APscheduler independent of subsequent deployments

Tags: python, django, jobs, apscheduler

I have a django application with a python AP scheduler running a specific job. I wish to run the job once every week. There might be subsequent deployments to the application and I do not want the scheduler to reset the jobs every time that happens. Is there any way to provide a past start date or check if a week has elapsed since the last run to ensure that the scheduler jobs run independent of deployments.

The scheduler code -

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(send_weekly_email, 'interval', weeks=1)
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The key challenge here is that your `BackgroundScheduler` does not persist job information across deployments/restarts. You could use the `APScheduler`'s built-in job stores, like `SQLAlchemyJobStore`, to persist the job across different sessions. However, that will not handle the scenario where a deployment happens less than a week after the last job was scheduled, leading to jobs being sent out more frequently than intended.

For that, I would recommend tracking the date of the last sent email separately, for example in a database or a simple file. Then, when the job is about to execute, it could check if a week has actually passed since the last email was sent. If not, it would skip the execution.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

# create a scheduler with SQLAlchemyJobStore
jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

def send_weekly_email():
    # path of the file storing the timestamp of last email sent
    last_sent_file = "/path/to/last_sent.txt"

    # check if it's time to send email again
    if os.path.exists(last_sent_file):
        with open(last_sent_file, "r") as f:
            last_sent = datetime.fromisoformat(f.read().strip())
            if datetime.now() - last_sent < timedelta(weeks=1):
                print("It's not yet time to send the email.")
                return

    # send the email here...
    
    # update the timestamp of last email sent
    with open(last_sent_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(datetime.now().isoformat())
    print("Email sent.")

# add the job
scheduler.add_job(send_weekly_email, 'interval', weeks=1)

# start the scheduler
scheduler.start()
```

Remember to replace "/path/to/last_sent.txt" with an appropriate path for your system.

Additionally, consider using the `logging` module instead of `print` for real-world applications. It would help you to keep track of when and why emails are (or aren't) sent.